# Krypton Contextmenu does not open under .Net FW 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-framework-version, krypton-toolkit

> Scenario

I'm using a very known kit of user controls, [Krypton](http://www.componentfactory.com/product?id=3), it comes with a contextmenu, a `KryptonContextMenu`.

I'm using the latest version which is **4.4.0**

I'm under Windows 8.1 x64, using VisualStudio 2013 Ultimate and using WinForms tech.

> Problem

I can't Show a `KryptonContextMenu` if I target my project to FW 4.0 or bigger. 
If I target FW 3.5 or smaller it works perfectly.

This happens with any project even with the official `KryptonContextMenuExamples` that comes with krypton project samples.

It does not throw any kind of exception, just if I try to use the `KryptonContextMenu .Show()` method using any of its overlads it does not show the contextmenu under FW 4.0, just does not happens anything.

> Question

1) I'm the only who has this issue with the `KryptonContextMenu`?, I just can't find information of this issue in the krypton page/forum.

2) I could try something to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I managed to fix it by changing the 'Platform target' of my application properties to 'x86' instead of 'Any CPU'. Then my KryptonContextMenu control is displayed correctly. I hope this will help you.